# How to hide no image items from Magento configurable options?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to hide configurable options that doesn't have any image associated. I tried to rewrite the configurable product block but it doesn't work. anyone has any idea about this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution is to set all simple products that don't have any pictures as out of stock and set the config `system->catalog->inventory->stock options->Display Out of Stock Products` to no.

If you have an product import logic you can integrate that code into that.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. I have already removed the image-less items from product listing. Now I need to remove the options from configurable. suppose if one configurable has 2 child items with size S and M. S has image and M doesn't. In this case I want to show only S. At present, both are showing and when I click on M, it shows no-image place holder.

Sorry, the above solution which you mentioned won't work here.

Comment: @JicksonJohnsonKoottala the solution is still relevent. if the simple product is out of stock then it won't show on the configurable options with the settings I mentioned.

Comment: @ shemaya sorry, still its not a good solution. because if I do this way, I need to come with another question like, how do I make simple product out of stock based on its image status. ? and that needs to be done on real time on detail page. I already found the answer by myself and posted on above. 

If you put product as out-of-stock, that will not show on configurable options, that is correct. but its not a good idea to make a out of stock only to hide it from this area. I hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution.
What I noticed, the configurable product options are coming from function `$this->getJsonConfig();` located at `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable` block. what I did is, I rewrite this block in my module and alter the function by putting the below code in it.

```
public function getJsonConfig()
    {
        $attributes = array();
        $options    = array();
        $store      = $this->getCurrentStore();
        $taxHelper  = Mage::helper('tax');
        $currentProduct = $this->getProduct();

        $preconfiguredFlag = $currentProduct->hasPreconfiguredValues();
        if ($preconfiguredFlag) {
            $preconfiguredValues = $currentProduct->getPreconfiguredValues();
            $defaultValues       = array();
        }

        foreach ($this->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
            if($product->getImage() && $product->getImage() != 'no_selection'){
                $productId  = $product->getId();
                foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
                    $productAttribute   = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                    $productAttributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
                    $attributeValue     = $product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());
                    if (!isset($options[$productAttributeId])) {
                        $options[$productAttributeId] = array();
                    }

                    if (!isset($options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue])) {
                        $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue] = array();
                    }
                    $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue][] = $productId;
                }
            }
        }
```

I just added `if($product->getImage() && $product->getImage() != 'no_selection'){` in allowed products foreach loop. This will only filter image items to configurable options json object array.